# Frequency of a column over a range of another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this

```
GeneID Score
ABC     0.1
EFH     0.2
ABC     0.5
STY     0.1
TRQ     0.2
TRQ     0.1
EFH     0.5
EFH     0.1
EFH     0.01
```

And I want to get a frequency of column 1 over the bin range of column 2 as follows:

```
<=0.1             4
>0.1 and <=0.5    4
```

Even if there are redundant values in column 1.Also if a particular value in column 1 appears twice in the same range, how do I count it just once?

Comment: Like this? `rbind("<=0.1" = sum(df$Score <= 0.1), ">0.1 & <= 0.5" = sum(df$Score > 0.1 & df$Score <= 0.5))
`

Comment: It seems like you need something like `table(df$Score > 0.1)` though your question isn't very clear. Not to mention that you have more than 8 values in the provided data set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, here's what I'd do:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(bin = ifelse(Score <= 0.1, "(,0.1]", ifelse(Score <= 0.5, "(0.1,0.5]", "(0.5,]"))) %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  summarise(N = n())
```

Which returns

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

        bin N
1    (,0.1] 5
2 (0.1,0.5] 4
```

Comment: I m sorry but I don't quiet get as to what does %>% represent .

Comment: `%>%` is a pipeline operator from the `magrittr` package but it's used heavily in `dplyr`. Try searching for a `dplyr` tutorial.

Comment: I did try to use this method and it looks really great but somehow once I got past %>% issue I was getting an error saying group_by function not found even after loading dplyr package

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `ifelse` statements here, just use `cut`

```
table(droplevels(cut(df$Score, c(-Inf, .1, .5, Inf))))
# (-Inf,0.1]  (0.1,0.5] 
#          5          4
```

Though if `Score` is bounded like in the provided data set, all you need to do is just to use `table` by condition

```
setNames(table(df$Score > 0.1), c(" <= 0.1", "> 0.1"))
# <= 0.1   > 0.1 
#      5       4
```

Comment: Thanks! the cut option worked the best and also was really simple to use.

Comment: Also if a particular value in column 1 appears twice in the same range, how do I count it just once? For eg in this case: TRQ falls in the same range of 0.1 to 0.5 twice, so I would just like to count the frequency as 1 for that range.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with package `plyr`

```
ddply(data, .(GeneID), summarize, frequency = (length(GeneID)/nrow(data)),
                                        range = max(Score)-min(Score))
```